# Join Two Tables and filter records in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to join two table values on `Room No`.

Here are my tables:

**RoomStatusTable**

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Room No   |   Type   |  Date     |  Descriprion  |
----------------------------------------------------
|  1        |    AC    |22 Jan 2015|   VA          |
|  2        |    AC    |22 Jan 2015|   VA          |
|  3        |    AC    |22 Jan 2015|   VA          |
|  4        |    AC    |22 Jan 2015|   VA          |
```

**RoomBooked Table**

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Room No   |   Type   |  Date     |  Descriprion  |
----------------------------------------------------
|  1        |    AC    |22 Jan 2015|   BK001       |
|  2        |    AC    |22 Jan 2015|   BLOCK       |
|  4        |    AC    |22 Jan 2015|   OC001       |
```

I need a result like the following:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Room No   |   Type   |  Date     |  Descriprion  |
----------------------------------------------------
|  1        |    AC    |22 Jan 2015|   BK001       |
|  2        |    AC    |22 Jan 2015|   Block       |
|  3        |    AC    |22 Jan 2015|   VA          |
|  4        |    AC    |22 Jan 2015|   OC001       |
```

Like this Table 1 contains all the records, however, table 2 only contains occupied records based on that change description as my result.

Comment: Why you have tagged MySQL and SQL server both? Which database system you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Left join` get data from both tables:

```
select r1.room_no,
       r1.Type,
       r1.Date, 
case when r2.Descriprion is null then r1.Descriprion else r2.Descriprion end as description   
from RoomStatus r1 
left join RoomBooked r2 on r1.room_no=r2.room_no
order by r1.room_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Coalesce function which return the first non null able value between the two description columns,

```
select r1.room_no,
       r1.Type,
       r1.Date, 
       coalesce(r2.Descriprion ,r1.Descriprion) As description   
from RoomStatus r1 
left join RoomBooked r2 on r1.room_no = r2.room_no
order by r1.room_no;
```